# css font-face not work in FF 37.0.1

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I generate a persian font by Font Squirrel Like This:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'b_yekanregular';
    src: url('dbs-byekan-webfont.eot');
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'b_yekanregular';
    src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2'),
         url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff'),
         url('dbs-byekan-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('dbs-byekan-webfont.svg#b_yekanregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Now in action font-face work in chrome but not work in FF(37.0.1).

Chrome true font:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTV1k.png

FF False font :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGcsR.png

How do can i fix this problem?